# Kotlin & Retrofit: Simple POST without Response

Tags: rest, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to do a POST Request with Kotlin and Retrofit where I'm only interested in the statuscode of the request. Tutorials I have seen solve it all a bit different and most of the time they do not compile any more or are very complicated.

Can someone help improving this code:?

```
interface ClientService {

        @POST("user/password-reset")
        fun passwortReset(@Query("email") email: String): Observable<Result>

        companion object {
            fun create(): ClientService {

                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl("https://test-backend.myurl.com/api/")
                        .build()

                return retrofit.create(ClientService::class.java)
            }
        } 
    }
```

I'm not sure how to call it and how to get the statuscode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this example

Under build.gradle:

```
   // retrofit

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"

    // rxandroid

    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

Interface:

```
interface APIService {

    @POST("register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun registrationPost(@Field("email") email: String,
                         @Field("password") password: String): Call<Registration>}


//**App Utils**

object ApiUtils {

    val BASE_URL = "your_url"

    val apiService: APIService
        get() = RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL)!!.create(APIService::class.java)

}
```

Retrofit Client:

```
object RetrofitClient {

    var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit? {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            //TODO While release in Google Play Change the Level to NONE
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
        }

        return retrofit

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
  //Variable declaration
  var mAPIService: APIService? = null

  //After oncreate

   mAPIService = ApiUtils.apiService

  //Some Button click

       mAPIService!!.registrationPost("SampleTest2@gamil.com", "123456").enqueue(object : Callback<Registration> {

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Registration>, response: Response<Registration>) {

                    Log.i("", "post submitted to API." + response.body()!!)

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        Log.i("", "post registration to API" + response.body()!!.toString())
                        Log.i("", "post status to API" + response.body()!!.status)
                        Log.i("", "post msg to API" + response.body()!!.messages)

                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Registration>, t: Throwable) {

                }
            })
```

Comment: What do you mean with the "after on create" comment in the MainActivity ? Do you mean in "onResume" function or at the end of "OnCreate" or something else ?
And also which of the libraries you must import for the "Callback<Registration>" there are plenty of libraries that is suggested from the Android Studio .

Answer (score 0):

Inside any function you have to call like:

```
 fun resetPassword(email:String) {

    val clientService = ClientService.create(APIConstants
            .BASE_URL_WORKSPACE)
    addSubscription(apiService.login(APIConstants.API_ACTION_LOGIN, userName, password,
            deviceid), object : APICallback<UserLoginResponse>() {
        override fun onSuccess(model: UserLoginResponse) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(model.errorMessage)) {
                mvpView.getDataSuccess(model, apiRequestCode)
            } else {
                mvpView.getDataFail(model.errorMessage, apiRequestCode)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(msg: String?) {
            LogUtil.e("Login Failure()- " + msg!!)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {}
    })
 }
```

You will get the success response/result in onSuccess() method.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot's of answers for the same question. Main Funda is to **Call Post API using Retrofit.**

Let me make some easier things to call Any API.

**In this Example of code. i used Demo API from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/**

First takes Permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Now go create one interface for Post API Response.

```
interface ApiInterFace {

    @POST("users")
    fun sendUserData(@Body userPost: UserPost) : Call<UserPost>

}
```

Now Comes to MainActivity or your Target Activity to call the API.
in this method i used static dummy data for user.

```
 private fun sendDataToApi() {

    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")  // Add Your BaseUrl here
        .build()


    val jsonPlaceHolder = retrofitBuilder.create(ApiInterFace::class.java)

    val userPost = UserPost(1,1,"New Added","Body of the title")  // Dummy Data

    val call = jsonPlaceHolder.sendUserData(userPost)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserPost>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserPost>, response: Response<UserPost>) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: "+response.code() )
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserPost>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: "+t.message )
        }
    } )    
    
}
```

**This is only based on simple example of Post the data to server. There MayBe having changes as per your cases.**